# Deploy to AWS S3 sync with github

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webpack, amazon-cloudfront, github-actions

I am trying to deploy static site to AWS S3 and Cloudfront with github action. My Github Action code is:

```
name: deploy-container

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'packages/container/**'

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: packages/container

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build

      - uses: chrislennon/action-aws-cli@v1.1
      - run: aws s3 sync dist s3://${{secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME}}/container/latest
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}}
```

But when I try to build I got these errors

[image: Github Actions 1]
[image: Github Actions 2]

Comment: As recommended in the error output, have you tried adding the env variable `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` and setting it to true for either your job or step?

Comment: I did it but still got the same error..

Answer (score 9):

GitHub will redeploy your application only if you did some change on a file inside of your application directory.
I suppose that you have changed only your yml file and tried to rerun the job on GitHub.
But from the error message, this is an unsecure method to use the tag ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS.
It is best to consider using the Official AWS for GitHub Actions instead of using the ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS.

```
name: deploy-container

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'packages/container/**'

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: packages/container

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets. AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-west-1

      - name: Copy files to the s3 website content bucket
        run:
          aws s3 sync dist s3://${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME }}/container/latest
```

Comment: This doesn't handle nested folder structure.

Answer (score 3):

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build

      - uses: chrislennon/action-aws-cli@v1.1
        env:
          ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: 'true'
```

Comment: - uses: chrislennon/action-aws-cli@v1.1
        env:
          ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS: 'true'

Answer (score 0):

You may want to restore modification time of the files so that only modified files are synced. For example using git-restore-mtime. Alternatively use something like dandelion though I haven't tried it.